# running laravel on a different port

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Bitnami MampStack on OS X 10.9. Because this is an inherited laptop, I had to set up Apache under MAMP to listen on port 8888. I tweaked it to listen on 8889 as well and added the following as a VirtualHost in my `httpd.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:8889>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/mampstack-5.4.26-0/apache2/htdocs/codebright/public"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "/Applications/mampstack-5.4.26-0/apache2/htdocs/codebright/public">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I followed the example [here](http://daylerees.com/codebright/build-an-app-one) (so all my source code matches his). The index blade works, but the `edit`, `create`, and `delete` blades return a 404.

As I was testing, I discovered that `http://localhost:8889/create` returned a 404, but `http://localhost:8889/index.php/create` returned the correct view. Also, browsing `http://localhost:8888/codebright/public/create` works as expected.

So...me being kinda new to Laravel and MVC frameworks in general, is there some way I can have this installing running properly on port 8889?

Answer (score 1):

Your virtualhost is working as it should, you just have now to be sure your public/.htaccess file is in place:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is the file that rewrites your urls removing the `/index.php` from them.

**EDIT**

Also, check if you have mod_rewrite installed and enabled, because your `.htaccess` uses it, in Ubuntu/Debian, to enable it, you have to execute:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: The `.htaccess` file is already there and matches what's listed here. Is there something in the virtualhost configuration I'm missing?

Comment: Since you dont have to add /public in your, your virtual host is working as it should, it's really the rewrite that's seems not working. Check if you have mod_rewrite installed and enambed, just edited to show you how to enable it, because usually it is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175513/mod-rewrite-in-vhosts-configuration). I was missing `AllowOverride All` in the `<Directory>` section. Updated `httpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:8889>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/mampstack-5.4.26-0/apache2/htdocs/codebright/public"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "/Applications/mampstack-5.4.26-0/apache2/htdocs/codebright/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I thought I might have been missing `RewriteEngine On` in the `VirtualHost` definition but it doesn't seem to have an effect on my problem.