# httpd.conf 301 redirects format with more then one domain hosted from server

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301, httpd.conf

We have rebuild our site and are looking to redirect about 1000
URLs. Looking around on the web it seems

```
Redirect 301 /oldlocation http://www.domain2.com/newlocation
```

is the string to use. I just wonder how the server knows the domain of
`/oldlocation` as it hosts more then one website. If we have two
websites with `/oldlocation` will both be redirected?

Is it possible to use

```
Redirect 301 http:full-old-url http:new-url
```

instead to make sure the server knows what old URL we are targeting?

Comment: Either put your .htaccess file in the folder of just the domain you require, or configure it in the relevant server block in your config file. [Here's a SO question explaining how to do this with virtual hosts.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175513/mod-rewrite-in-vhosts-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

In Redirect directive's pattern ,you can match against the URI (url part after the hostname) ,not the host.  To match against HOST, you will need to use mod-rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example1.com
RewriteRule ^/?oldpath http://example2.com/newpath [L,R=301]
```

The example above will redirect all requests from **example1.com/oldpath** to **example2.com/newpath** .

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for your answer, much appreciated.